# SQL Server : add 'Type' to every column in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `DemoTable` in SQL Server. And it has these columns:

```
Column1, Column2, Column3
```

I want to query the table

```
select * from DemoTable
```

but in query results I want to concatenate `Type_` to all the column names available in `DemoTable`.

So the result of this query should be showing columns

```
Type_Column1, Type_Column2, Type_Column3
```

Is there any function or any way to achieve this?

Note: there are N number of columns not only 3 just to rename only these manually.

Comment: Don't think so.

Comment: What have you tried ? You can maybe use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS , join it with your table, and alias the new columns with the `COLUMNS` table type column

Comment: @sagi Okay, I have multiple Tables in my database, i have joined all the tables and i am getting query results, After joining all the tables , there are many duplicate column names(column which are used to join) ,So real problem of this is , I'm not able to create view out of this query results, So i thought if i pretext the table name to all columns would help !!!

Comment: The only way I know how to do such a thing in pure t-sql is using dynamic SQL (which you can't use in a view) so I don't think what you're asking for is possible.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Okay Thank you

Comment: A dynamic sql in a procedure probably.  But if it's just 1 table with a fixed layout, just hardcoding the alias names in a view would probably be best. On second thought, how about creating the view with hardcoded aliases via dynamic sql...

Comment: It sounds like what you really want is an application (or one serious CLR function) that can take an arbitrary T-SQL `select` query, parse it, then walk the list of output expressions and (re)name them by prepending the source table name. (Don't forget to handle self-joins!) This is, in a word, nontrivial. (How do you name arbitrary expressions, e.g `A.Foo - B.Bar` or `Min( Shoe.Size )`?)

Comment: I don't get this. Instead of `create view xyz as select a.col1, a.col2, b.col1, b.col3 ...` select the column just once `create view xyz as select a.col1, a.col2, b.col3 ...` or use alias names `create view xyz as select a.col1 as acol1, a.col2 as acol2, b.col1 as bcol1, b.col3 as bcol3...`. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to automate your task using dynamic SQL:

```
use MY_DATABASE;
go
--here you specify all your parameters,  names should be self-explanatory
declare @sql varchar(1000) = 'select ',
        @tableName varchar(100) = 'DemoTable',
        @prefix varchar(10) = 'Type_';

select @sql = @sql + name + ' as ' + @prefix + name + ',' from sys.columns
where object_name(object_id) = @tableName;

set @sql = left(@sql, len(@sql) - 1) + ' from ' + @tableName;

exec(@sql);
```

Answer (score 3):

If the problem is as you say:

> After joining all the tables , there are many duplicate column names

then the typical solution is to **NOT use `*`**. So instead of this:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
JOIN B ON ...
JOIN C ON ...
```

... you should consider using a custom column set, which is the normal and recommended way to do this, as in the following example:

```
SELECT A.Column1, A.Column2, B.Column3, C.Column4, C.Column5
FROM A
JOIN B ON ...
JOIN C ON ...
```

Comment: I'd also add the caveat that if you're still left with multiple columns you want in the result set that have the same names but different values, it may be time to consider whether the data model is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Some general remarks:

- Naming your result set's columns dynamically will demand for dynamic SQL in any case. No way around...
- Naming columns to carry extra information is - in most cases - a very bad idea.
- the only way I know to deal with the *asterisk* in a `SELECT * FROM ...` and still get full control over the columns names and types is XML.

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * 
FROM sys.objects 
FOR XML RAW, ROOT('TableDef'),ELEMENTS, XMLSCHEMA,TYPE
```

This will return the 10 first rows of `sys.objects`. The result is an XML, where the rows follow an XML schema definition.

It is possible (but sure not the best in performance) to create a fully inlined query dynamically. The result will be an *EAV* list carrying everything you need.

```sql
WITH PrepareForXml(QueryAsXml) AS
(
SELECT
    (
    SELECT TOP 10 * 
    FROM sys.objects 
    FOR XML RAW, ROOT('TableDef'),ELEMENTS, XMLSCHEMA,TYPE
    )
)
,AllRows AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RowIndex
          ,rw.query('.') theRowXml
    FROM PrepareForXml
    CROSS APPLY QueryAsXml.nodes('TableDef/*:row') A(rw)
)
SELECT RowIndex
      ,B.ColumnName
      ,B.ColumnValue

      ,COALESCE(
      (SELECT QueryAsXml.value('declare namespace xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
                                 (TableDef
                                 /xsd:schema
                                 /xsd:element
                                 /xsd:complexType
                                 /xsd:sequence
                                 /xsd:element[@name=sql:column("ColumnName")]
                                 /@type )[1]','nvarchar(max)') 
        FROM PrepareForXml)
      ,(SELECT QueryAsXml.value('declare namespace xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
                                 (TableDef
                                 /xsd:schema
                                 /xsd:element
                                 /xsd:complexType
                                 /xsd:sequence
                                 /xsd:element[@name=sql:column("ColumnName")]
                                 /xsd:simpleType
                                 /xsd:restriction
                                 /@base)[1]','nvarchar(max)') 
        FROM PrepareForXml)
        ) AS ColumnType
FROM AllRows
CROSS APPLY theRowXml.nodes('*:row/*') A(col)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT col.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') ColumnName
                   ,col.value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') ColumnValue ) B;
```

This is the beginning of the result-set:

```
RowIndex    ColumnName  ColumnValue ColumnType
1           name        sysrscols   sqltypes:nvarchar
1           object_id   3           sqltypes:int
1           schema_id   4           sqltypes:int
[...many more...]
```

I don't know what you need actually, but it might be enough to export the XML *as is*. It's everything in there...

### UPDATE: I did not read carefully enough...

You want to trick out the fact, that a result set's column names must be unique in order to continue with this...

The approach above will not solve this issue. Sorry.

I won't delete this immediately... Might be there are some hints you can get out of this...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to add 'Type' to every column in table:

```
SELECT Column1 AS Type_Column1, Column2 AS Type_Column2, Column3 AS Type_Column3
FROM DemoTable
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that `Type_` should be using the real column's type...

Comment: @Shnugo the OP wrote in the 3rd comment to the question, "...i pretext the table name to all columns..."